# Javascript assign an selector's text content to a form input value

Tags: javascript, forms

$('#Price') shows this value: " $123,000 ". I want to assign this value to a form text input field in the form of "123000". Here is my code:

```
var numberString = $('#Price').text();
var removeSpace = numberString.replace(" ", "");  
var removeDollarSign = removeSpace.slice(1);
var resultValue = + removeDollarSign.replace(/,/g, ''); 
myForm['inputname'].value = resultValue;
```

I get NaN result. I also tried to convert resultValue to number by using Number() function, but that didn't help. What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
myForm['inputname'].value = $('#Price').text().replace(/,|\s|\$/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var resultValue = + removeDollarSign.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Should be:

```
var resultValue =  removeDollarSign.replace(/,/g, '');
```

You are not concatenating, you're just assigning to a NEW variable.

Comment: I can see the problem here, but somehow the code returned a blank field, the result didn't show up. I still believe this is the right answer as I test it somewhere else it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Keep it simply by using a REGEX that does it all in one step, as Musa has shown.

Comment: I totally agree! Thanks so much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you should remove plus sign

```
  // Wrong
 var resultValue = + removeDollarSign.replace(/,/g, ''); 
  // correct
 var resultValue = removeDollarSign.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this with (remove all non-digits):

```
myForm['inputname'].value = $('#Price').text().split('.')[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Comment: This one works in this specific example, but if the content is " $123,000.00 ", would it turn out to be "12300000"?